# Deleted answer gone after editing it. Can't undelete it, nor post it again

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-answers

I was about to answer a question, but realized that I missed an important point. So I deleted my answer to avoid getting downvotes.

After I edited my answer and pressed the save button my answer was gone. Usually it's greyed out and I can click undelete - not this time.

My workaround:
I could browse back and copy&paste my answer. Then I wanted to post my answer again, but it said that my answer couldn't be posted because it's a duplicate of <question title>.

I had to add nonsense text to my answer so I could post it. Then I had to edit my answer again to remove the nonsense text.

Please solve this issue or tell me a better workflow.

Comment: you're saying you don't see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738265/mysql-make-datetimes-more-recent/10738840#10738840?

Comment: Reproduced, I can't see my own deleted answers anymore.

Comment: The same happend to me today.

Comment: @balpha That's the question, yes. Can't see it.

Comment: Reproduced. Looking...

Comment: Shortly after a moderator made me see an important mistake on one of my answers, downvotes starting to appear and I deleted it. I didn't see it anywhere and assumed that the moderator did some black magic to totally delete it, I was a little bit mad and almost leave a comment, what if I find a way to improve my post?, etc? but I didn't complain. Good to know it was a bug and not the moderator

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sorry about that; indeed a recent change caused this behavior, this was unintentional. You should always be able to see your deleted answers (unless the question itself is deleted). Thanks for noting.

The fix for this is being rolled out; you should be able to see the answer again in a few minutes.

Comment: Does this finally apply to seeing our own deleted questions?

Comment: No. To see a deleted question, you need 10k rep, as always.